# Changing location and direction of axes

Tags: plotting, graphics

I need to produce a plot that looks something like this:

[image]

from a function definition where `z` (the vertical axis) is the independent variable. I can easily invert the function, so making the vertical axis the dependent variable is easy. But I can't find a way to orient the system as it is in the picture, with `x` values increasing from left to right, and `y` values from top to bottom, with the axes as shown. I've found several related questions on this site, but nothing that specifically addresses this issue, nor can I find a `Plot` option that solves my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
LogLinearPlot[Exp[x], {x, .1, 100},
 Epilog -> {
   Lighter@Blue, Line[{{-3, -15.0}, {Log@100, 0}}], 
      Text[Style["Lake 1", Lighter@Blue], {0.5, -10}],
   Darker@Red, Line[{{-3, -22.5}, {Log@100, 0}}], 
      Text[Style["Lake 2", Darker@Red], {0.5, -15}],
   Darker@Green, Line[{{-3, -30.0}, {Log@100, 0}}], 
      Text[Style["Lake 3", Darker@Green], {0.5, -20}]
   },
 AspectRatio -> 1,
 AxesLabel -> {100*l[z]/l[0], z},
 ImageSize -> 400,
 PlotRange -> {{0, 100}, {-30, 0}},
 Ticks -> {Automatic, Map[{-#, #} &, Range[0, 30, 5]]}]
```

[image]

Comment: So the trick (which I should have seen) is to make the vertical axis actually the negative of what you want and just relabel it. Cute.

Answer (score 6):

you need to work with `Frame` and `FrameTicks`, something like this:

```
LogLinearPlot[30 - 30 Exp[-x], {x, .1, 100}, 
 Frame -> {{True, False}, {False, True}},
 PlotRange -> {{.1, 100}, {0, 30}},
 FrameTicks -> {{Table[{i, 30 - i}, {i, 0, 30, 5}], None},
   {None, {.1, 1, 10, 100}}},
 Epilog -> Table[Line[{{Log[.1], 30 - s},
     {Log[100], 30}}], {s, {15, 22, 30}}]]
```

note plot thinks the vertical axis goes from 0 at the bottom to 30 at the top, so we fix the ticks to `{{0, 30}, {5, 25}, {10, 20},...` and also transform the function as `30-f[x]`.  Quit a bit of fiddling required but unfortunately i don't think there is a more direct way.

[image]

Comment: OP also wants the y-axis flipped.

Comment: see edit.. ....

Comment: Seems like a pretty common request; I'm surprised there's no easier way. But this works great. Thanks.